# Fill inside of an filtered contour OpenCV Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image that has green borders which encapsulates the items that has to be deleted. 
I have filtered the only green part of the image so my next step is to fill inside of the filtered contour with a different color then I will remove that part from the image? I am very open the any suggestions. 
Here is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imageio

## Read
img = cv2.imread("test.png",-1)
img2 = imageio.imread("test.png")
## convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)
# mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (86, 255,255))
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255,255))

## slice the green
imask = mask>0
green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
green[imask] = img[imask]

green_filter=img[100,100,0]
print(green_filter)


## save 
cv2.imshow('image', green)
cv2.imshow('  ',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print(img)
print(green)
```

image i have: https://ibb.co/vJX1jM4
image i reached currently:https://ibb.co/FnScYHc

Comment: Use `cv2.fillConvexPoly` to fill the contour.

Comment: could u please provide an example

Comment: cv2.drawContour can fill the contour. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc Set the thickness to -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio

## Read
img = cv2.imread("test.png",-1)
## convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255,255))
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
idx = 0 
mask1 = np.zeros_like(img) 

cv2.drawContours(mask1, contours, idx, (255,255,255), -1) 
out = np.zeros_like(img)
out[mask1 == (255,255,255)] = img[mask1 == 255]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(16, 4))
for ax, image in zip(axs, ['img', 'mask1', 'out']):
    ax.imshow(eval(image))
    ax.set_title(image)
    ax.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

=>

[image: Processing]

I let you play around with this snippet, especially if you want to remove your green contour.

If you want to reverse the kept area, you need to replace:
`out[mask1 == (255,255,255)] = img[mask1 == 255]`
by:
`out[mask1 == (0,0,0)] = img[mask1 == 0]`
(see second figure below)

[image: Reverse result]

I just imported [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) for convenience here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the quick and dirty sudo code here, but this is generally how you would go about it.

```
Load in image
Convert to grayscale
Find Contours
Find the index of the contour you want to fill
Use fillConvexPoly to fill the specific contour with the index found above.
```

Here is some code that can guide you in the right direction.

```
#Read in the image
img = cv2.imread("test.png")

#Convert to grayscale
grayImg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Find contours
contours = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#Find contour index that you want
#I didn't put code here because I don't know what index would work for your image,
#But you can manually find it by just drawing each contour found one by one until
#You get the contour you want, then use that index to fill it.

#Fill the contour
#NOTE: You will have to adjust this function for your own code
cv2.fillConvexPoly(img, contours[index], lineType=8, shift=0)
```